# Bootstrap tooltip position inside collapsed div

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

Im creating a bootstrap accordion with collapsed panels to hold form input. Im trying to create a tooltip inside a collapsed panel above the input for validation output.

- Submit button is pressed it calls setTooltip function of each input.
- Header panel (opens collapse content) then calls displayTooltip.

PROBLEM: When the panel is opened from collapse,all the tooltips are positioned around 50px above the input at (requires a collapse and open to repostion to correct place).

Can anyone suggest a method for refreshing the tooltip that is inside the collapsed div or somehow resetting its position to correct place above input?

EDIT- The placement is correct when submitting and calling setTooltip and the div is not collapsed.

```
function setTooltip(obj, value, pos) {
    options = {placement: pos, trigger: 'manual'}

    $(obj).tooltip(options)
            .attr('data-original-title', value)
            .tooltip('fixTitle');
}

function displayTooltip(obj) {
    options = {placement: "top", trigger: 'manual'}

    $(obj).tooltip(options).tooltip('show');
}
```

Comment: Can you perhaps provide more code? Perhaps a JSFiddle? To actually see your problem in action?

Comment: If you could include the html, or better yet, create a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/new), we will be better able to assist you.

Comment: I created [this bootply](http://www.bootply.com/IOa6jA55jJ), which seems to work fine...I think we need to see your HTML

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example JSFiddle where I use bootstrap tooltip in combination with a accordion object.

Is this  what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/dheLm7u6/

JQUERY:

```
$(function () {
    $('#buttonid').click(function()
    {
        if( !$('.test1').val() ) {
              $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('show');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: This is similar....im currently trying to recreate my setup with JSfiddle, but havnt used it b4+ my code is v complex! My issue is that im setting the tooltip from a button external to the div and when the div is collapsed (this is when i have issues!). This is why i split the display and set functions to try and fix it.

Comment: I tried editing your fiddle to recreate sympton to no avail. I like how u assigned tests to classes, i just looped thru all form input and ran a validation if id matched!